# Crash while assigning element to another array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have 2 arrays defined like so...

```
var smt_List_Offline: NSMutableArray = []
var smt_List_OfflineTemp: NSMutableArray = []
```

Now elsewhere I'm doing this...

```
self.smt_List_OfflineTemp = self.smt_List_Offline[0] as! NSMutableArray //CRASH HERE
                           
                          
self.smt_List_Offline.removeObject(at: 0)
```

But by doing this, I get a crash like indicated above with the message `Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x1b2345678) to 'NSMutableArray'`

Comment: What is the content of smt_List_Offline?

Answer (score 0):

This `self.smt_List_Offline[0]` is a dictionary not an array so cast it to `NSMutableDictionary/[String:Any]`

```
let smt_List_OfflineFirst = self.smt_List_Offline[0] as! NSMutableDictionary
```

or

```
let smt_List_OfflineFirst = self.smt_List_Offline[0] as! [String:Any]
```

Comment: It's throwing an error @Sh_Khan. It says..`Cannot assign value of type '[String : Any]' to type 'NSMutableArray'`. The cast to `NSMutableDictionary ` also throws error..

Comment: `smt_List_OfflineTemp ` should be a dictionary also as you expect a dictionary not an array

Comment: Ok @Sh_Khan. But `smt_List_Offline` is still an `NSMutableArray `. That's fine right..?

Comment: BTW you can do `self.smt_List_Offline = [smt_List_OfflineFirst ]` but note it's what should not be followed

Comment: BTW you can do `self.smt_List_Offline = [smt_List_OfflineFirst ]` but note it's what should not be followed

Comment: You mean like this..` self.smt_List_OfflineTemp = self.smt_List_Offline.firstObject as! NSMutableArray`

Comment: i mean you can change eother lhs/rhs to the other as you like you have a different array and a dictionary objects

Answer (score 0):

The error is very clear `smt_List_Offline` cannot be cast to type `NSMutableArray`. When you use `as!` you are telling the compiler this should crash if the casting is unsuccessful, so you should use `as?` instead.

```
if let smt_List_OfflineFirst = self.smt_List_Offline[0] as? NSMutableArray {
    smt_List_OfflineTemp = smt_List_OfflineFirst
} else { print("Can't cast smt_List_OfflineFirst to NSMutableArray") }
```

Comment: It's not going inside the `if-let` @Frankenstein...So its not casting..

Comment: Yes, because you're trying to cast an unrelated type to `NSMutableArray`, it should be `NSDictionary` or `NSMutableDictionary` instead.